# MYSQL import from excel row import error 1364

Tags: mysql, excel, csv, import-csv

Hello everyone please bear with me, im a student and im still learning,

so im trying to import data from an excel CSV file into my database, this method worked for me on every table except for my orders table which has a lot of foreign keys, when i tired to import data like i did before i keep getting an error related to default value for column, i managed to get some data by doing column by column but when i try the rest i get errors. any ideas? also some of the screenshots got cut off but rest assured my table is complete.

[My table so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZUHb.png),[error when trying to import only quantity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytaNd.png),[error when i try to import IDs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00r2h.png),[code for my orders table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCOFU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your source does not contain data for column `OrderNumber`. So import wizard does not mention this column in LOAD DATA / INSERT statement. The column have no default value. Server does not know what value must be assigned into this column. An error is generated.

You may:

**Option 1.** Alter table structure and add default value for this column. For example,

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
    CHANGE COLUMN OrderNumber OrderNumber INT NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

Replace datatype/length with one you need. Set another default value if needed (for example, zero). Remove NULL (or replace with NOT NULL) if needed.

**Option 2.** Edit your source (Excel file) and add a column with the name `OrderNumber` and some value which you need. Then export this changed file to CSV and import into the table.

Comment: my excel file already has the column OrderNumber however i inserted that first before everything, would that affect anything?

Comment: @R3cklessRay You use some (unknown for me) importing tool... I cannot answer. I'd prefer to import CSV data using native LOAD DATA INFILE.

Comment: i use the data import wizard that mysql has built in.

Comment: @R3cklessRay MySQL is database server, it have no any wizard.Wizard is some client software. Built-in - maybe, you mean Workbench? Anycase I'd recommend you to use importing query, not wizard - in this case you may control the importing process completely.

Comment: oh sorry about that, yes im working in workbench and i will try the importing query

Answer (score 0):

Set default value for the empty `varchar`

ex -:

```
create table table_name ( 
     orderNumber varchar(255), 
     CREATED_BY varchar(40) DEFAULT '' not null
);
```

Comment: should i set the default value on everything in my table though? i have values that i inserted into the one mysql is telling me no default value.